# Unable to catch custom event

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I managed to emit a custom event but can't seem to catch that event in another component.

Here's the emitter:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'x-hamburger-button',
    template: `
        <div (click)="toggleSidebar()">
           <i class="fa fa-bars">
              <a href="#"></a>
           </i>
        </div>
        `
})

export class HamburgerButton {
    @Output() toggled = new EventEmitter();
    toggleSidebar = function () {
        this.toggled.emit();
        console.log('toggled.emit()');
    };
}
```

and this is the receiving component:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { HamburgerButton } from './hamburger-button.component';

@Component({
    selector: "x-sidebar",
    template: `
        <div (toggled)="onToggled()" [ngClass]="{collapsed: collapsed}">
        </div>
        `
})

export class Sidebar {
    collapsed: boolean = false;
    onToggled = function () {
        this.collapsed = !this.collapsed;
        console.log('event caught');
    };
}
```

I get `toggled.emit()` on my console, but there's no `event caught`. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I abandoned the idea of emitting and catching an event, because there is no parent child relation between the sidebar and the hamburger button (which collapses or expands the sidebar).

Instead, I glued these together by injecting a service instance that is held by a common parent object (Window).

Here's how:

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class SidebarService {
    private sidebarToggledSource = new Subject();
    sidebarToggled$ = this.sidebarToggledSource.asObservable();

    toggleSidebar(collapsed: boolean) {
        this.sidebarToggledSource.next({});
    }
}
```

This service exposes an observable `sidebarToggled$` that components can subscribe to. A fresh instance of `SidebarService` is then injected into the `Window`component:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { NavigationBar } from './navigation-bar.component';
import { Sidebar } from './sidebar.component';
import { SidebarService } from './sidebar.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'x-window',
    directives: [NavigationBar, Sidebar],
    template: `
            <x-navigation-bar></x-navigation-bar>
            <div>
                <x-sidebar></x-sidebar>
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        `,
    providers: [SidebarService]
})

export class Window {
    constructor (private sidebarService: SidebarService) { }
}
```

That same instance is then injected into the child components (do not add them to the `providers` array or else you'll get a new instance which is disconnected from the one in the parent component!):

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { SidebarService } from './sidebar.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'x-hamburger-button',
    template: `
        <div (click)="toggleSidebar()">
           <i class="fa fa-bars">
               <a href="#"></a>
           </i>
        </div>
        `
})

export class HamburgerButton {
    constructor (private sidebarService: SidebarService) { }
    toggleSidebar() {
        this.sidebarService.toggleSidebar(true);
    };
}
```

and

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { SidebarService } from './sidebar.service';

@Component({
    selector: "x-sidebar",
    template: `
        <div [ngClass]="{collapsed: collapsed}">
            <ul>
                <li>Menu Item 1</li>
                <li>Menu Item 2</li>
                <li>Menu Item 3</li>
                <li>Menu Item 4</li>
                <li>Menu Item 5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        `,
    styles: [
        ...
    ]
})

export class Sidebar {
    collapsed: boolean = false;
    constructor (private sidebarService: SidebarService) { 
        sidebarService.sidebarToggled$.subscribe(data => {
             this.collapsed = !this.collapsed;
             console.log('event caught');
        });
    }
}
```

So, if `HamburgerButton` is clicked, `toggleSidebar` on `SidebarService` is invoked. There's only one instance of `ServiceSidebar` (created in `Window`) which gets injected into the child components, so `Sidebar`, which has `subscribe`d to the observable `sidebarToggled$`of that same service will have its function invoked, i.e. the `collapsed` property of `Sidebar` is toggled. This property can now be used with `ngClass` in the `styles` section of `Sidebar`, collapsing or expanding it.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the changes carefully .
**Note**: *this code refers to TypeScript*

```
export class HamburgerButton {
    @Output() toggled = new EventEmitter();
    toggleSidebar() {                  //changed
        this.toggled.emit('Angular2'); //value emitted

    };
}
```

---

```
@Component({
        selector: "x-sidebar",
        template: `
            <x-hamburger-button (toggled)="onToggled($event)" [ngClass]="{collapsed: collapsed}">               //changed
            </x-hamburger-button>      //changed
            `
    })


export class Sidebar {
    collapsed: boolean = false;
    onToggled(value) {                //changed
        this.collapsed = !this.collapsed;
        console.log(value);           //Angular2 <--------
    };
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I can only catch custom events from child components (see above, hamburger button is inside sidebar now)?

Comment: Have you checked my code? What is the relation betn hamburger and sidebar? Is there any? You import hamburgerbutton in sidebar but why? To answer this all ques, look at my code carefully.

Comment: Yeah, I tried your solution but it didn't work, at least not for me. I imported hamburger-button because I read in another post that that was required (for the event to be known? no idea). What stopped me dead in my tracks was, that you put another hamburger-button inside sidebar (where I don't want to be for obvious reasons - collapse the sidebar and button is gone). Anyway, I'm gonna try to set this up in a different manner with a service brokering between sidebar and hamburger-button, see how that goes.